# missing dependant extensions for pusher

Tags: laravel-5, pusher

I have All extension loaded in my LEMP stack,
and laravel, everything is set up correctly
but when I try to broadcast and event i get this error[image]

can any body tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're missing some packages the pusher library needs to send messages. You'll need to install the relevant packages using whichever package manager you use.

eg:

```
apt-get install php-curl php-json
```

Comment: The curl extension was missing! I installed  php-curl php-curl json